# Can I exclude HTML output when there's no result in mysql database when querying via PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

In short, I have a PHP output (the code is only part) which needs to be hyperlinked when displayed on the webpage, but the issue is, when there's no result, it hyperlinks a blank URL. Is there anyway to not display the HTML if there's no result when the search is executed?

To clarify, I'd need to apply this to more than 1 section of the output.

Here's the specific part of the code.

```
if(isset($_POST['search'])) {

$searchq = $_POST ['search'];
$query = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM HH_list2 WHERE Company LIKE '%$searchq%'") or die ("could not search"); //OT TO HERE !!!!!
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($count == 0) {
    $output = 'Sorry but we did not find anything';
    }else{
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            $Company = $row ['Company'];
            $Twitter_ID = $row ['Twitter_ID'];
            $Online_chat = $row ['Online_chat'];
            $Online_form = $row ['Online_form'];
            $Email_1 = $row ['Email_1'];
            $Email_2 = $row ['Email_2'];
            $Email_3 = $row ['Email_3'];

            $output .= '<div style="background-color:#ebebeb; padding: 2em;"> <h3>'.$Company.' </h3><br/> Twitter: <a href="http://www.twitter.com/'.$Twitter_ID.'" target="_blank">'.$Twitter_ID.'</a><br/> <a href="'.$Online_chat.'" target="_blank">Online Chat</a> <br/> <a href="'.$Online_form.'" target="_blank">Online Form</a><br/>'.$Email_1.'<br/>'.$Email_2.'<br/>'.$Email_3.'</div>';


        }

}
```

}

Comment: Could you post your code of you querying the database? All you need to do is check if that comes back as empty or not and work with it in an IF/ELSE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use `empty()` function

```
if(!empty($Twitter_ID)){
$output .= '<div style="background-color:#ebebeb; padding: 2em;"> <br/>
Twitter: <a href="http://www.twitter.com/'.$Twitter_ID.'" target="_blank">'.$Twitter_ID.'</a>
</div>';
}
```

Reference [php empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Regarding your second problem

```
if(isset($_POST['search'])) {

$searchq = $_POST ['search'];
$query = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM HH_list2 WHERE Company LIKE '%$searchq%'") or die ("could not search"); //OT TO HERE !!!!!
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($count == 0) {
    $output = 'Sorry but we did not find anything';
    }else{
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            $Company = $row ['Company'];
            $Twitter_ID = $row ['Twitter_ID'];
            $Online_chat = $row ['Online_chat'];
            $Online_form = $row ['Online_form'];
            $Email_1 = $row ['Email_1'];
            $Email_2 = $row ['Email_2'];
            $Email_3 = $row ['Email_3'];

            $output .= '<div style="background-color:#ebebeb; padding: 2em;">';
if(!empty($Company)){
 $output .= '<h3>'.$Company.' </h3><br/> ';
 if(!empty($Twitter_ID)){
 $output .= 'Twitter: <a href="http://www.twitter.com/'.$Twitter_ID.'" target="_blank">'.$Twitter_ID.'</a><br/>';
}
 if(!empty($Online_chat)){
  $output .= '<a href="'.$Online_chat.'" target="_blank">Online Chat</a> <br/> ';
}
 if(!empty($Online_form)){
 $output .= '<a href="'.$Online_form.'" target="_blank">Online Form</a><br/>';
}
 if(!empty($Email_1)){
 $output .=$Email_1.'<br/>';
}
 if(!empty($Email_2)){
 $output .=$Email_2.'<br/>';
}
 if(!empty($Email_3)){
 $output .=$Email_3;
}
 $output .='</div>';


        }

}
```

---

> [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: You're a star, thank you. I'll mark it as the answer in a few mintutes when I can :-)

Comment: I'm still having trouble. I know it's my understanding that's the issue, but I think I should disclose the full code so you can see. Any help appreciated:

Comment: Thanks everyone once again :-)